# Eclipse: Open in New Window

Tags: eclipse

In Package Explorer I right-clicked on project and selected "Open in New Window". New Eclipse window was opened with that project. Then I closed old, "main" Eclipse window, so only new "project" window remained.

Now each time I launch Eclipse I have this "project" window with project name in window title and Package Explorer drilled down into this project. And I need to press "Up" button in Package Explorer to see all my projects.

How can I restore default behaviour and launch Eclipse with workspace scope and not project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My original answer: Once you get the Package Explorer the way you want it, if you exit Eclipse cleanly it should come back that way.

My revised answer: It looks like a bug, even if you exit cleanly it comes back inside of the project. And in fact when you create a new window no matter what it puts you into the project. Even if you switch to the project explorer.

I found a way to fix it though, do a Window -> Close All Perspectives, then open the Java perspective and exit and come back in and you should be OK. I have filed this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367301) about it.

Answer (score 2):

Close the project properly " File --> Close All", Then restart eclipse.
OR you can create a new work space " File --> Switch Workspace --> Other..."

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure this is what you are looking for but the [Documentation](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#workspace) offers a command line option to select the start workspace:

> The workspace is the physical location (file path) you are working in.
> You can choose the workspace during startup of Eclipse or via the menu
> ( File → Switch Workspace → Others.